# tensorflow in virtualenv not finding gpu device

Tags: tensorflow

I am on a Linux machine with Python installed, on which I can see the Graphics card with `nvidia-smi`.

When I list the local devices within tensorflow,

```
python3 -c "from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib; print(device_lib.list_local_devices())"
```

I correctly see two devices, a CPU and a GPU.

However, if I boot a virtualenv and I install tensorflow on it,

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/Python3 ~/.virtualenvs/test
source ~/.virtualenvs/test/bin/activate
pip install tensorflow
```

the command to list devices,

```
python3 -c "from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib; print(device_lib.list_local_devices())"
```

does not output the GPU device. What is missing here?

I suspect that the CUDA libs are not being found by tensorflow, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use gpu, the correct python package is `tensorflow-gpu`, not `tensorflow`.

Comment: that is no longer the case. Yet I seem to have the same issue that OP has.